# Difference between these two?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cctype>                   // Character testing and conversion  
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  char letter = 0;                  // Store input in here  

  cout << endl
       << "Enter a letter: ";       // Prompt for the input  
  cin >> letter;                    // then read a character  


  if(std::isupper(letter)) {             // Test for uppercase letter  
    cout << "You entered a capital letter."
         << endl;
    cout << "Converting to lowercase we get "
         << static_cast<char>(std::tolower(letter)) << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  if(std::islower(letter)) {             // Test for lowercase letter  
    cout << "You entered a small letter."
         << endl;
    cout << "Converting to uppercase we get "
         << static_cast<char>(std::toupper(letter)) << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  cout << "You did not enter a letter." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here in this example, what is the difference between using 'std::' `if(std::isupper(letter)) {` and not using 'std::' `if(isupper(letter)) {`?

I tried both and they return the same result so I'm not sure what would be the benefit of using 'std::'

Comment: without the std::, you'll call a function named isupper() from the current scope, and if there isn't any, from the global namespace (::isupper()). Writing std::isupper() refers to a function names isupper() in namespace std.

Comment: @namezero not if you're stupid and use `using namespace std;`

Comment: Some slight differences.  `std::isupper()` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isupper/) and `isupper()` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/).

Comment: Using `std::` before `isupper` guarantees that this will compile with every C++ compiler ("implementation"). It is unspecified whether `isupper` is *also* found in the global namespace when including `<cctype>`.

Comment: I understand that '::' means global scope. (Is that right?)

Is there a case where not using std:: would give an error?

Comment: @Jamal The first one doesn't apply here, it takes a `locale` as second parameter.

Comment: @Cole: If we're going to be pedantic, by using namespace std; you alias isupper() in the current scope/namespace; hence you're still calling isupper() from in the current scope :]

Comment: @DyP: I know, but I was just noting the differences based on name.

Comment: So 'std::' is sort of a safe approach? When do I have to use std::?

Comment: You use `std::` when you're using something from the STL.  For instance, `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting namezero user comment:

*without the std::, you'll call a function named isupper() from the current scope, and if there isn't any, from the global namespace (::isupper()). Writing std::isupper() refers to a function names isupper() in namespace std*